# Center align a jtable into a jscrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I am using NetBeans. I turned off the auto-resize of `JTable` columns. Now it is aligned to the left side of scroll pane. How can I make it centered?

Comment: In your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), please identify the layout of the container to which you add your `JScrollPane`.

Comment: Its a panel which is a tab of a tabpen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Have to add an extra panel.

```
public class GUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 40));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button);
        JScrollPane scrollableArea = new JScrollPane(panel);
        frame.add(scrollableArea);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Really a great and unexpected solution. Sometime java really acts weird. Here is the orginal post http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t600361-jscrollpane.html